# Dataframe index is not set properly in pandas/quandl

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = pd.DataFrame(quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL'))
print(df.head())
```

When I imported data from Quandl, this is how the data was imported as shown in the image.

But i don't want the date to be the index, instead, i want the index to be normal nos like 0, 1.... and so on

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: hhhmm interesting, I copied your code and it worked, are you sure ? try to add the `inplace=True`